# How do i know if my data is really been transmitted using SSL on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, heroku, https

Here is my cenario:

I have an Rails app on Heroku and i'm forcing it to use HTTPS (Using this tutorial: http://simonecarletti.com/blog/2011/05/configuring-rails-3-https-ssl/) .

I created a POST form, and its the action is "/my-action"

How do i know if my data is really been transmitted using SSL ? I mean, the form action shouldn't "https://mywebsite.herokuapp.com/my-action" ?

Some considerations: 
* I'm using the free heroku SSL (https://myapp.herokuaapp.com )
* This app is not using the heroku SSL endpoint addon

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have valid `ssl` certificate and `encryption` key, then you only your data is accepted  via `ssl`. Simply redirecting your website to use `https` protocol doesn't encrypt your data flow. And, this is what you were doing it. Right now, you are using heroku which does provide free SSL service if you use its domain.

So, if your website can be accessible via https://myapp.herokuapp.com and browser isn't giving  any warning..then you are using SSL service.

This isn't applied if for custom domains. Your custom domain will still be accessible  with https://www.example.com but it it SSL enabled.

Comment: So, there is something wrong on heroku docs? "SSL Endpoint is only useful for custom domains. All default appname.herokuapp.com domains are SSL-enabled already and can be accessed simply by using https, e.g., https://appname.herokuapp.com."[https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint)